# Como tipar la respuesta de una api en Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy trabajando con Strava. Tengo todas las clases creadas, para trabajar con POO y mi duda es la siguiente.

Como veis en la imagen siguiente, tengo bien tipado el Athlete que recibo, pero no soy capaz de tipar los array que tiene dentro (en este caso se ve bikes, que es de tipo Array, pero debería de ser de tipo Bike)

[image: Código de la respuesta de strava]

Me podéis ayudar de como tipar la respuesta de una api en base a las clases ya creadas? Para una vez recibida la respuesta, taparla completamente y poder usar los tipos de las propiedades?

Servicio y clases

Servicio desde donde invoco a la API de strava, quiero que de este servicio ya llegue a los controladores la respuesta, un objeto de tipo Athlete que contiene 3 listas (a parte de sus propiedades especificas), una de ellas sería una lista de `Club`, no un Array genérico

```
async getAthlete() {
        return this.interactionService
            .get<Athlete>('/athlete', headers)
            .pipe(map((resp) => new Athlete({ ...resp })));
    }
```

Esto devuelve un objeto `Athlete`, como se ve en la consola

Pues bien ahora me gustaría conseguir eso mismo con las listas que contiene, porque luego, en otras partes de la aplicación necesito saber que tipo de objeto me llega para hacer ciertas funciones.

Clase Athlete

```
import { AthleteBase } from './athlete-base.class';
import { Bike } from './bike.class';
import { Club } from './club.class';
import { Shoe } from './shoe.class';

export class Athlete extends AthleteBase {
    can_follow: boolean = false;
    follower_count: number = 0;
    friend_count: number = 0;
    mutual_friend_count: number = 0;
    athlete_type: number = 0;
    date_preference: string = '';
    measurement_preference: string = '';
    clubs: Club[] = new Array<Club>();
    ftp: number = 0;
    bikes: Bike[] = new Array<Bike>();
    shoes: Shoe[] = new Array<Shoe>();

    constructor(athlete?: Athlete) {
        super(athlete);

        if (athlete != null) {
            this.can_follow = athlete.can_follow;
            this.follower_count = athlete.follower_count;
            this.friend_count = athlete.friend_count;
            this.mutual_friend_count = athlete.mutual_friend_count;
            this.athlete_type = athlete.athlete_type;
            this.date_preference = athlete.date_preference;
            this.measurement_preference = athlete.measurement_preference;
            this.clubs = new Array<Club>(...athlete.clubs);
            this.ftp = athlete.ftp;
            this.bikes = new Array<Bike>(...athlete.bikes);
            this.shoes = new Array<Shoe>(...athlete.shoes);
        }
    }
}
```

Como veis contiene las 3 listas, os dejo el código de la clase Club, por no saturar la pregunta y una vez conseguida tipar esa lista, poder actuar igual con el resto

Clase Club

```
export class Club {
    id: number = 0;
    resource_state: number = 0;
    name: string = '';
    profile_medium: string = '';
    profile: string = '';
    cover_photo?: null | string = '';
    cover_photo_small?: null | string = '';
    sport_type: string = '';
    city: string = '';
    state: string = '';
    country: string = '';
    private: boolean = false;
    member_count: number = 0;
    featured: boolean = false;
    verified: boolean = false;
    url: string = '';
    membership: string = '';
    admin: boolean = false;
    owner: boolean = false;

    constructor(club?: Club[]) {
        if (Array.isArray(club)) {
            club.forEach((club) => {
                this.id = club.id;
                this.resource_state = club.resource_state;
                this.name = club.name;
                this.profile_medium = club.profile_medium;
                this.profile = club.profile;
                this.cover_photo = club.cover_photo;
                this.cover_photo_small = club.cover_photo_small;
                this.sport_type = club.sport_type;
                this.city = club.city;
                this.state = club.state;
                this.country = club.country;
                this.private = club.private;
                this.member_count = club.member_count;
                this.featured = club.featured;
                this.verified = club.verified;
                this.url = club.url;
                this.membership = club.membership;
                this.admin = club.admin;
                this.owner = club.owner;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

El objetivo final es el de conseguir una aplicación angular + typescript en POO. Sólo lo estoy haciendo para aprender y sacarme las estadísticas de mi entrenamientos, carreras, etc y si luego en un futuro a alguien le sirve, pues genial. Por eso no busco ningún "apaño" sino meter tiempo en afianzar ese conocimiento.

Cualquier cosa que veais mal en el código, será de agradecer que lo comentéis.

Comment: La captura que muestras es de la consola del navegador, en donde Typescript no se ejecuta, sino Javascript. Exactamente ¿qué te propones? Una cosa es cómo manejas los tipos durante el desarrollo y otra muy deiferente cómo los recibes durante la ejecución. Typescript no se ejecuta directamente en el navegador. El navegador no entiende de tipos, interfaces, ni nada de las estructuras añadidas a Typescript. En el navegador se ejecuta Javascript (al menos hasta la fecha de este comentario). Lo que llamas *tapar* (entiendo te refieres a asignar un tipo), sólo ocurre durante la etapa de desarrollo.

Comment: De la [documentación](https://www.typescriptlang.org/): *Typescript añade sintaxis adicional a Javascript para permitir una __integración más estrecha con su editor.__ Capture errores pronto en su editor*. Cuando el código en Typescript es transpilado a JS, todo tipo se pierde, ya que los tipos son exclusivos de Typescript. ¿Podrías aclarar qué quieres hacer exactamente? Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras he dejado las clases y el servicio que conforman esta petición para aclarar algo mas el como esta montada la estructura de datos.

Comment: Creo que esto ya lo habíamos discutido en algún momento. Uno de los desafíos más grandes que tienes es que la OOP de Javascript (sí, Typescript es JavaScript a fin de cuentas) no es la clásica OOP que puedes conseguir en lenguajes como C#. La herencia en JavaScript se basa en prototipos, por lo cual, tratar de aplicar inferencia sobre tipos en Javascript no funcionará de la misma forma que funciona en otros lenguajes. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Exacto, lo habíamos hablado, pero como no conseguí nada, lo estaba intentando enfocar de otra manera, por ver si no os había entendido. Pues nada, si typescript no es capaz de esto... acaba de perder muchísimos puntos a mi parecer

Comment: Trataré de darte una respuesta para intentar aclarar un poco más el porqué lo que intentas hacer no funciona como esperas, y alguna alternativa a cómo lograrlo, aprovechando lo que sí funciona en JS. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Mauricio, por el momento, visto este funcionamiento, voy a volver a trabajar con interfaces, si el POO completo no es posible, voy a tomar la de no complicarme tanto, cuando reciba tu respuesta, volveré a ver si es posible tipar y ver las clases como se debe :D si no, tiraremos de métodos que devuelvan el tipo de objeto con el que estoy trabajando. Muchas gracias

Comment: Si las clases son solo contenedores de datos, sin comportamiento, es una perdida de tiempo que los mapees a clases, pero para los anidados tienes que hacer lo mismo que has hecho con `Athlete`. Para el caso de `Club` tendrías que hacer algo así `this.clubs = athlete.clubs.map(club => new Club(club));`

Comment: Realmente lo queria mapear a clases por que en ciertos componentes, dependiendo de la clase debe hacer una cosa u otra, lo he solucionado cargando un elemento nuevo a la interfaz, pero no me parece del todo fino

Comment: hay operadores typeof, instanceof..>function createInstance(TheClass: typeof Bike,, parametros que requiere) { 
  return new TheClass(parametros que requiere);
}-->const bike = createInstance(Bike, parametros);
assert.ok(point instanceof Bike);https://alligator.io/typescript/instanceof-guard/

Comment: Genial articulo, lo revisaré en profundidad

Answer (score 0):

Debes generar una interface para el objeto bike, el siguiente código cumple con dicho proposito:

```
interface Bike {
    id: string;
    primary:  string;
    name:  string;
    resource_state:  string;
  }
  
  interface Athlete {
    id: string;
    username:  string;
    athlete_type:  string;
    bikes:  Bike[] | null;
  }
  
  var json = '{"id":579974,"username":"Roger","athlete_type":2,"bikes":[{"id":91460,"primary":"true","name":"bike_David","resource_state":5},{"id":54301,"primary":"true","name":"bike_Aaron","resource_state":9}]}'
  
  var athlete:Athlete = JSON.parse(json);
  
  console.log(athlete);
```

Para que se te facilite la generación de las respectivas interfaces puedes usar [esta herramienta](https://jvilk.com/MakeTypes/) que genera interfaces desde un JSON.

Saludos :)

Comment: Tengo todo montado con clases, de hecho, estoy intentando montar una aplicación POO. Te dejo el código de todo lo relacionado con la pregunta en el primer post.